# Tkinter Grid Manager (TypeError)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to put a set of 16 pictures into a tkinter frame. I've created a dictionary that maps the image address name (stored in imgbutton) as a key to the dictionary imagedict the value of which is a string containing its position in the tkinter grid (example a button in column 0 and row=1 would have the name backgroundpic5.jpg and the value "01").

Each row contains 4 pictures and there are 4 rows in total. The PhotoImage equivalent of imgbutton is buttonphoto (created using PIL). However, when i try running this, it tells me the grid_configure command accepts on 2 arguments while i have given 3 (Type Error)

```
Pos=imagedict[imgbutton]
GridColumn=Pos[0]; GridRow=Pos[1]
Button= tk.Button(root, image=buttonphoto)
Button.grid(GridColumn, GridRow)
Button.pack()
```

The error statement,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ComputerProject\Tester2Imagebg.py", line 44, in <module>
  Button.grid(GridColumn, GridRow)
  TypeError: grid_configure() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the error.  It knows what it's talking about ... well anyway it tells you something.  Look up the documentation for `Tkinter.Button.grid` and it will tell.  You need to do `Button.grid(column=GridColumn, row=GridRow)`

You see, the error is right.  You gave one too many arguments to `Button.grid()`.  Using `Button.grid(...)` is really just a shortcut for `tk.Button.grid(Button, ...)`, so all together you gave three arguments, but `.grid()` is expecting a button instance, `cnf`, and some keyword arguments.  You provide the button instance by using `Button.grid(...)` instead of `tk.Button(...)`, but you gave two other positional arguments.  You need to provide the column and row numbers as keyword arguments.

Comment: I have understood the error but could you explain why it considers the grid configure statement being given 3 arguments?

Comment: @LeroyJD: I've edited my answer a couple times in the last minute or two.  If anything is unclear, feel free to ask me again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax of the [`grid()` layout manager options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method):

```
 Button.grid(column = GridColumn, row = GridRow)
```

Comment: Check [`grid()` layout manager options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) correct syntax.

Comment: The values don't have to be integers. A string representation of an integer is perfectly fine.